# Outlook Web Addin, appointment

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I have previously been asking about add-in in this section of Outlook, but I have a new requirement now that I can't seem to figure out how to address.

I have a button that appears on appointments for both Organizer and Attendee. The button works as intended for both parties.

However, we have now been made aware that there are several users who are working with shared calendars, in which they are not Organizer nor Attendee.
For these users the button is visible but it is in a "disabled" state and can not be clicked.

So my question is: How do I configure the button (I expect it can be done in the manifest somehow) so that it is also available for people looking at shared calendars (aka not as organizer nor as attendee).

Any help is appreciated, thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible today.

However, we track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](//officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins).

It looks like the feature you want has been requested by others already. Please upvote the [existing request](//officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/11634318-support-for-shared-mailboxes).

Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

[Outlook Add-ins Engineering Team]